# how to refer values based on column names in python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, oracle

i am trying to extract and read the data from a SQL query.
Below is the sample data from SQL developer:

```
target_name    expected_instances   environment   system_name         hostname
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
ORAUAT_host1   1                    UAT           ORAUAT_host1_sys    host1.sample.net
ORAUAT_host2   1                    UAT           ORAUAT_host1_sys    host2.sample.net
```

Normally i pass the system_name to the query (which has a bind variable for system_name) and get the data as a list,but not the column names.
Is there a way in Python to retrieve the data along with the column names and reference values with column name like target_name[0] giving the value ORAUAT_host1?Please suggest.Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `cx_Oracle` ? If so, do you want to retrieve the column names from the `cx_Oracle.cursor` method ? You should publish the code you want to amend, it would help us to understand better the problem

Comment: @RobertoHernandez yes i am using cx_oracle..will try the cursor method.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to get the column names from the table you are querying, you can do something like this:

My example is printing a csv file

```
import os
import sys
import cx_Oracle 

db = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass@host:1521/service_name')
SQL = "select * from dual"
print(SQL)
cursor = db.cursor()
f = open("C:\dual.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
r = cursor.execute(SQL)

#this takes the column names
col_names = [row[0] for row in cursor.description]

writer.writerow(col_names)

for row in cursor:
   writer.writerow(row)
f.close()
```

The way to print the columns is using the method description of the cursor object

> **Cursor.description**
> This read-only attribute is a sequence of 7-item sequences. Each of
> these sequences contains information describing one result column:
> (name, type, display_size, internal_size, precision, scale, null_ok).
> This attribute will be None for operations that do not return rows or
> if the cursor has not had an operation invoked via the execute()
> method yet.
>
> The type will be one of the database type constants defined at the
> module level.

https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#